# ValueError: substring not found, please save me

Tags: python, sorting, valueerror

So, I am trying to make a sorter that sorts text by its chronological order on a paper.

The  algorithm:

```
def ordered(o, p):
    return sorted(o, key=lambda x: p.index(x))

print(ordered(text, ee))
```

Unfortunately, it returns as so:

```
ValueError: substring not found
```

I tried changing the parameters, because the last time I ran it, it worked. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Here is the text:

```
ee = '''
The Civil War: Secession and Strengths/Weaknesses

Secession
The 1860 presidential race showed just how divided the nation had become. The Republicans were united behind Lincoln. The Democrats, however, had split between Northern and Southern factions [faction: a group of people within a larger group who have different ideas from the main group] , with Northern Democrats nominating Stephen Douglas for president and Southern Democrats supporting John C. Breckinridge of Kentucky. The election became even more confusing when a group called the Constitutional Union Party nominated John Bell of Tennessee.
Abraham Lincoln Is Elected President With his opposition divided three ways, Lincoln sailed to victory, but it was an odd victory. Lincoln won the presidential election with just 40 percent of the votes, all of them cast in the North. In ten Southern states, he was not even on the ballot.
For white Southerners, the election of 1860 delivered an unmistakable message. The South was now in the minority. It no longer had the power to shape national events or policies, and Southerners feared that, sooner or later, Congress would try to abolish slavery. And that, wrote a South Carolina newspaper, would mean “the loss of liberty, property, home, country—everything that makes life worth having.”
The South Secedes from the Union In the weeks following the election, talk of secession filled the air. Alarmed senators formed a committee to search for yet another compromise that might hold the nation together. They knew that finding one would not be easy, but they still had to do something to stop the rush toward disunion and disaster.
The Senate committee held its first meeting on December 20, 1860. Just as the senators began their work, events in two distant cities dashed their hopes for a settlement.
In Illinois, a senator named Lyman Trumbull asked President-Elect Abraham Lincoln whether he could support a compromise on slavery. Lincoln's answer was clear. He would not interfere with slavery in the South, and he would support enforcement of the Fugitive Slave Act. However, Lincoln drew the line at letting slavery extend into the territories. On this question, he declared, “Let there be no compromise.”
Meanwhile, in Charleston, South Carolina, delegates attending a state convention voted that same day—December 20, 1860—to leave the Union. The city went wild as church bells rang and crowds filled the streets, roaring their approval. A South Carolina newspaper boldly proclaimed, “The Union Is Dissolved!” Six more states soon followed South Carolina's lead, and in February 1861, those states joined together as the Confederate States of America.
The Civil War Begins On March 4, 1861, Lincoln became president of the not-so-united United States. In his inaugural address, Lincoln stated his belief that secession was both wrong and unconstitutional. He then appealed to the rebellious states to return in peace. “In your hands, my dissatisfied fellow countrymen, and not in mine,” he said, “is the momentous issue of civil war.”

The following month on April 12, 1861, Confederates in Charleston, South Carolina, forced the issue when they opened fire on Fort Sumter, a federal fort in Charleston Harbor. After more than 30 hours of heavy shelling, the defenders of the fort hauled down the Stars and Stripes and replaced it with the white flag of surrender.
The news that the Confederates had fired on the American flag unleashed a wave of patriotic fury in the North. All the doubts that people had about using force to save the Union vanished. A New York newspaper reported excitedly, “There is no more thought of bribing or coaxing the traitors who have dared to aim their cannon balls at the flag of the Union . . . Fort Sumter is temporarily lost, but the country is saved.”
The time for compromise was over. The issues that had divided the nation for so many years would now be decided by a civil war.








North Versus South
President Abraham Lincoln's quick-and-clear response to the attack on Fort Sumter was to call for 75,000 volunteers to come forward to preserve the Union. At the same time, Jefferson Davis, the newly elected president of the Confederacy, called for volunteers to defend the South. For the first time, Americans were fighting a civil war.
Strengths and Weaknesses of the North The North began the war with impressive strengths. Its population was about 22 million, compared to the South's 9 million. Additionally, with about 90 percent of the nation's manufacturing and most of its banks, the North was both richer and more technologically advanced than the South.
The North had geographic advantages, too. It had more farms than the South to provide food for troops, and its land contained most of the country's iron, coal, copper, and gold. The North controlled the seas, and its 21,000 miles of railroad track allowed troops and supplies to be transported wherever they were needed.
The North's greatest weakness was its military leadership. At the start of the war, about one-third of the nation's military officers resigned and returned to their homes in the South. During much of the war, Lincoln searched for effective generals who could lead the Union to victory.
Strength and Weaknesses of the South In contrast to the North, the South's great strength was its military leadership. Most of America's best military officers were Southerners who chose to fight for the Confederacy, which was not an easy decision for many of them. Colonel Robert E. Lee, for example, was not a supporter of either slavery or secession, but he decided that he could not fight against his native Virginia. Lee resigned from the U.S. Army to become commander in chief of the Confederate forces.
The South had geographic advantages as well. To win the war, the North would have to invade and conquer the South, but the sheer size of the South made this a daunting task. The South, in contrast, could win simply by defending its territory until Northerners became tired of fighting.
The South did have an important geographic disadvantage. If the Union gained control of the Mississippi River, it would divide the Confederacy in two.
The South's main weaknesses were its economy and its transportation systems. The region's agriculturally based economy could not support a long war, and the South had few factories to produce guns and other military supplies. The Confederacy also faced serious transportation problems because the South lacked the railroads needed to haul troops and supplies over long distances.
Abraham Lincoln Versus Jefferson Davis The North's greatest advantage was its newly elected president, Abraham Lincoln. Through even the darkest days of the war, Lincoln never wavered from his belief that the Union was perpetual—never to be broken. Throughout his presidency, Lincoln related the preservation of the Union to the ideals of the American Revolution. In his first inaugural address, he said that the Union was begun by the American Revolution, “matured and continued” by the Declaration of Independence, and affirmed by the Constitution.
At the time of the secession crisis, Jefferson Davis was a U.S. senator from Mississippi. A firm believer in states' rights, he resigned his seat in the Senate when Mississippi left the Union. Like Lincoln, Davis often spoke of the American Revolution. When Southerners formed their own government, Davis said in his inaugural address, they “merely asserted a right which the Declaration of Independence of 1776 had defined to be inalienable.” He believed the South was fighting for the same freedom cherished by the nation's founders.









    '''
```

Here is the extracted text that has to be ordered by the function:

```
text = ['in Charleston, South Carolina',
        'On March 4, 1861',
        'In his inaugural address',
        'six more states soon followed south carolina',
        'Confederates in charleston, south carolina',
        'after more than 30 hours of heavy shelling',
        'The time for a compromise was over',
        'The news that the confederates had been fired',
        'Republican candidate abraham lincoln won']
```

And the output, I don't know. I am running it so that I can find the precise order of these extracts in the big text.

Comment: what are you calling the function with? what inputs?

Comment: Please share an input for example and expected output.

Comment: I apologise, I added the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting happens when `str.index` can't find the substring you're searching for. You can see this in a simpler example:

```
"some string".index("foo") # not found, raises ValueError
```

There are a few ways you might be able to deal with this issue.

One option is to use a different string method to search for your substrings. The `str.find` method searches for a substring in the same way that `str.index` does, but it returns `-1` instead of raising an exception if the substring is not found. That may or may not be what you want, since it will sort the unmatched substrings before all the ones that do match somewhere.

Another option is to first filter your inputs to see which strings won't match before you try calling `index` on them to find exactly *where* they match. It may be that you can transform them in some way to fix things up, or you could just skip over those substrings. For example:

```
text = [substring for substring in text if substring in ee] # exclude non-matching strings
```

And a final option is to decide that this is an issue with your input data and fix it at the source. Maybe you're not supposed to have any non-matching substrings. If that's the case, you should figure out which ones are not matching and why, and fix them! I'd note that you have some odd capitalization in several of your strings (like "abraham lincoln" and "south carolina"), and those won't match if the capitalization in the main text is different. In this context, getting an exception from `str.index` is a feature, not a bug, since it points out a data error!

Comment: Thank you so much! I realised that the str.find method was better, and I think my shoddy capitalisation skills played a big role!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some strings from `text` list are not found in the text, that is why `index()` raises a ValueError exception. You can filter your data before sorting and exclude extra elements or use `find()` instead of `index()` because it returns -1 if an element is not found (instead of raising an exception). Using the latter approach, you will get a list where elements that were not found in the text are in the beginning, which may not correspond to your goal.

Comment: Sorry, @Blckknght's answer arrived first, but your answer is also very detailed, and I like it!

Comment: Good luck with your program! :)